# HTML - Keep user filled fields and display on next page when "submitted"

Tags: javascript, html

I have a real basic html order form that asks for name, address, credit card info, billing/shipping info. Here's a sample of my html.

```html
<fieldset>
 <legend>Personal information:</legend>
 <form>
<label>
  First Name
  <input type="text"><br>
</label>
<label>
  Last Name:
  <input type="text"><br><br/>
</label>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>Billing Address</b>

Street Address:
<input type="text" id="address_1">

(City, State, Zip):
<input type="text" id="address_2"> <br/>

<input type="checkbox" id="toshipping_checkbox">
<em>Check this box if Shipping Address and Billing Address are the same.</em> <br/>
<b>Shipping Address</b>

Street Address:
<input type="text" id="shipping_address_1">

(City, State, Zip):
<input type="text" id="shipping_address_2">
```

Upon submission of this form I would like the `results.html` to print out the previously filled out fields.

Something like this:

```
You've entered the following data:
firstname="whatever first name entered"
lastname=
address=
```

basically take all input `id`'s and print them out as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a script for printing

```
 <script type="text/javascript">


        function PrintDiv() {
            $('document').ready(function () {


                var divContents = document.getElementById("WOcontainer").innerHTML;
                var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=800,width=1024');
                printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Personal Information</title>');
                printWindow.document.write('</head><body style=" font-family: Arial; font-size: 10px;" >');
                printWindow.document.write(divContents); 
                printWindow.document.write('</body> </html>');
                printWindow.document.close();
                printWindow.print();
            })
        }


    </script>
```

Event handler

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="PrintDiv();" />
```